# Replicate the actualFontSize pointer return in Deprecated sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize to get the change in font size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, fonts, sizewithfont

So,

in `sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize`, we pass a pointer for actualFontSize which can then be used to shrink the font within a label. As in :

```
[s sizeWithFont:self.font
                minFontSize:minimumScaleFactor
                actualFontSize:&actualFontSize
                    forWidth:width
                lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];
```

So now, we can do `self.frame.font.pointSize = actualSize` to modify the font size. My question is : Now that sizeWithFont is deprecated, how do I get this pointer back?

Basically, the recommended method to replace it is `boundingRectWithSize` :

```
[s boundingRectWithSize:CGSize(width,CGFLOAT_MAX)
                options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin)
                attributes://An NSDictionary with font
                context:nil];
```

But as you can see, it only returns the size. I thought of doing something like :

```
changeInFontSize = (newSize.height - oldSize.height) + (newSize.width - oldSize.width)
                   -------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                  2
```

But this doesn't really give me the answer I want. Could someone help me about how to do this? To be precise - I need the difference in the font size to change the current font size!

Comment: possible duplicate of [sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize workaround in iOS7 to get actualFontSize pointer back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083678/sizewithfontminfontsizeactualfontsize-workaround-in-ios7-to-get-actualfontsize)

Comment: Please don't repeat your questions. The proper thing to do is to update your previous question as needed.

Comment: Hmmm... I actually want to close that one. This is an update on the question.

Comment: Deleted the old question. Could you look at this one now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `sizeWithFont` method reduces the fontsize as needed. So if the function used a smaller font size, how do you know which size it used? That's the `actualFontSize` for!! From the documentation:

> Although it computes where line breaks would occur, this method does
>   not actually wrap the text to additional lines. If the entire string
>   does not fit within the given width using the initial font size, this
>   method reduces the font size until the string does fit or until it
>   reaches the specified minimum font size.

The new recommended method `boundingRectWithSize` does not reduce the fontsize. So if the function does NOT reduce the fonsize, meaning, it will use the size you specify in `attributes`, there's no need to return the actual size used (because it's exactly the one you specified, hence, you already know it).

EDIT:
If you want to calculate the font size needed to fit in some predefined bounding box, you would need to *test* with a few point sizes and calculate the one that fits best. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818189/nsstring-font-size-specific-to-frame-width) for some examples (the last answer on the link looks interesting to optimize efficiency)

Comment: Yes, thanks for telling me that. My question is, irrespective of the method now, given that I can only get the sizes back, can I scale the font sizes?

Comment: So what you're asking is 'how can i calculate the font size needed to fit in some predefined bounding box?' ?